# Sendmail commandline issue

Tags: centos, sendmail

I am trying to send mail from commandline using :

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail xyz@mail.com
```

This works fine and shows subject , however I cannot add body to this. If I use

```
echo "Hello Hello" | sendmail xyz@mail.com
```

I get "Hello Hello" in body but now no subject. What is the correct way to get both without using any external file as all examples i could find use external files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Submit headers and body via sendmail's standard input. Separate headers and body by empty line.

Command line:

```
(echo "Subject: test"; echo; echo "Hello Hello") | sendmail -i xyz@mail.com
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i xyz@mail.com <<END
Subject: test

Hello Hello
END
```